# html table in Gmail's body

Tags: html, html-email

I'm etcetera SDK to insert  snapshot into a mail and send it from Unity. But I'm also inserting text into this email. I want it to be formatted in the form of a table. The code that I have written looks formatted when I open it in iPhone mail app but not in Gmail app on Android. Can somebody tell me if I'm going wrong somewhere ?

However, if I send the mail from iPhone to my gmail account, it looks perfectly fine. It is only when I open the mail app to send the content, it looks bad. Only the 
 tags will be considered but not the table tag later on.

The code might not be of the highest standard but here it is

```
 body = "<html><body>" + divDeviceInfo + "<br>";
    body += "Unity Version = " + Application.unityVersion + "<br>";
    body += "Selected Server URL = " + LoginScreenSet.SelectedServerUrl + "<br>";
    body += "SVN Version " + string.Format("{0}.{1}", Config.BUNDLE_VERSION, Config.SVN_REVISION) + "<br>";
    body += "Client: " + client + "<br>"; 
    body += "Player Name: " + LiveData.Player.name + "<br>"; 
    body += "Player ID: " + LiveData.Player.player_id + "<br>"; 
    body += "Device ID: " + DeviceBridge.GetSavedUdid() + "<br>";
    body += "Hardware: " + UnityEngine.SystemInfo.deviceModel + "<br>";
    body += "Device: " + UnityEngine.SystemInfo.deviceName + "<br>";
    body += "OS: " + UnityEngine.SystemInfo.operatingSystem + "<br>";
    body += "OS Version: " + os_version + "<br>"; 
    body += "Client Version:" + Config.BUNDLE_VERSION + "<br>"; 
    body += "Client Revision:" + Config.SVN_REVISION + "<br>"; 
    body += "Static Data: " + StaticData.Inst.DataVersion + "<br>";
    body += Environment.NewLine;


    List<LogEntry> _recentLogs = Logger._recentLogs;

    string[] _recentLogsInString = new string[_recentLogs.Count];
    int i = 0;


    //start the table and put headings
    logs = "<table><tr><th>ThreadID</th><th>TimeStamp</th><th>Level</th><th>Channel</th><th>Message</th></tr>";
    foreach (LogEntry _entry in _recentLogs)
    {


        logs += "<tr><td>"+ _entry.ThreadId.ToString() +"</td>";
        logs += "<td>" + _entry.Timestamp.ToString() + "</td>";
        logs += "<td>" + _entry.Level.ToString() + "</td>";
        logs += "<td>" + _entry.Channel.ToString() + "</td>";
        logs += "<td>" + _entry.Msg.ToString() + "</td></tr>";

    }
    //End the table
    logs += "</table></body></html>";
    body += logs;
```

Comment: It seems to me that this is fundamentally an HTML question, nothing much to do with Unity directly. Recommend you focus on raw HTML, find something that works, and reverse engineer from there. Consider tags such as [tag:android], [tag:html], [tag:email], or [tag:html-email].

Comment: If its a HTML issue like @rutter is saying then could you provide the code of the HTML that is giving you the problem or at the very least a screen screen shot?

Comment: That cody in the question is all the html code that I have written. I pass that as the body of the message to the mail app which in this case is Gmail. Its not perfectly html because I'm embedding it inside a string which then gets processed by the mail app

Comment: what crazymatt is referring to and is integral to this discussion is the rendered markup that you actually see in the email clients. so not just the code to render it, but what is actually output in HTML.

Comment: I will try to upload a screenshot in sometime because I test it on mobile. So I need to take one there and upload it. 

So what it does, it strips all the tags that I have added and displays everything as just one long continuous text paragraph. However the break tags come into effect for the first few lines and starting from

`//start the table and put headings` , its just one long paragraph which actually should have been in the form of a table

Answer (score 0):

html email rendering engines are typically in the stone age. your best bet will be to use archaic attributes like `align` and `hspace`, `vspace`. not sure which engine gmail is using, but you can look that up and see which attributes will target it.

Comment: The weird part is Gmail recognizes the <br> but totally disregards everything after that. Anyway, I'll try what you suggested. Thanks!

Comment: emailonacid is a great tool for email testing